# Partial match filename with list elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, wildcard, filenames

Filenames in a folder:

```
abc jik1.csv ; abc lkj6.csv ; abc rty8.csv ;  
xyz poi4.csv ; xyz jgh7.csv
```

`List: ['abc','xyz']`

Through loop:
I want to import files into a `df`, say all files starting with the first element of the list i.e. `abc` do some calculation and then import files starting with second element `xyz` by looping and so on.

Problem: How to combine `abc` list-element with wildcard * so that the files name becomes `abc*.csv` which will let me import 3 `abc` files into a `df`?

Tried:

```
for lst in lst:
   element = lst[0:3]
   print(element)    
   df = pd.read_csv( element +'*.csv' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `glob`

```
from glob import glob
files = glob('abc*.csv')

for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

To get all the files:

```
files = glob('abc*.csv') + glob('xyz*.csv')
```

for multiple file prefixes:

```
files = [glob('{}*.csv'.format(i)) for i in ['abc', 'xyz']]
```

it will give you a list of lists of all the files names.

Comment: I have to get partial file name abc from the list, not manually as there are several files.

Comment: It should get all the file with `abc` in the beginning and `csv` in the end.